# How to add all .pri files inside a directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

I've searched quite thoroughly, but couldn't find a way to get all the folders inside a directory. I have the following qt project structure

```
first/
    second/
       - second.pri

    third/
       - third.pri
    ...
    first.pri
```

I want to include all the pri files inside the first.pri file. I can do

```
include($$PWD/second/second.pri)
include($$PWD/third/third.pri)
...
```

But the problem is there could be many sub directories added in the future and I want to automatically include all the pri files. I've tried

```
FILES = $$files($$PWD/*/*.pri)
for(FILE, FILES) {
    include($$FILE)
}
```

But this does not find the folders inside 'first' folder. [$$files documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false) allows specification of recursive, but it does not descend into subdirectories. How do I achieve it?

Comment: Do you have only those 2 levels? or you want a fully recursive solution?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I have three levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `QMAKE` function lists recursively all the files below a directory:

```
# - Function that list all files below a directory
defineReplace(list_recursively) {
    FILES = $$files($$1)
    RESULT =
    for(var, $$list($$FILES)) {
        exists($$var)
        {
            RESULT *= $$find(var, .*\.pri)
            RESULT *= $$list_recursively($$var/*)
        }
    }
    return($$RESULT)
}

# - Define the base directory
DIR = $$PWD/*

# - Test the function
temp_dir = $$list_recursively($$DIR)

# - Output the result 
for(var, $$list($$temp_dir)) {
    message($$var)
}
```

In the `list_recursively` function, it is possible to filter only those files with a specific extension, for example `.pri`. This is not even required if your project structure contain only `.pri` file.

Note: QMake does not work correctly with white spaces, it is usually a good idea to avoid them.

EDITED:

Added a filter for .pri files.

Comment: How do I get only the pri files? I tried, ($$var/*.pri), but it does not print anything.

Comment: @akashrajkn: I added a filter for .pri files. Hope it help.